# dynamic fill and create a structure in oData with SAP Hana Calculation View

Tags: dynamic, odata, hana

What i try to do is to create an oData Service based on a SAP Hana Calculation View. All my data is stored in one view. If new data occurs i join the new views in my view that collects all that data. This view is shown in the picture below.

[View to collect data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZzKL.png)

Now i want to create an oData-Service that dynamically creates a structure. So when a view is joined to my actual view, the structure should be updated with all the new attributes, so that i don't have to change my oData again and again.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The whole point of oData structures is to be relatively stable interfaces between systems. If you break/change them unilaterally the service clients likely run into issues.